# Rewriting MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to rewrite a MySQL query to MSSQL, but it's not as easy as I thought, since the functions from MySQL are not used in MSSQL(2014).

My MySQL query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(versions.Name, ': ', versions.Version)),
                    ',',
                    ', </br>') AS VersionString
        FROM
            target
                LEFT JOIN
            versions ON versions.targetid = target.id
        WHERE
            target.TestJobId = testruns.TestJobId
                AND versions.Name = 'SW') AS NameVersion
FROM
    testruns
```

I've tried to rewrite it, but I can't seem to make it work.

```sql
SELECT 
    (SELECT stuff(
            (SELECT DISTINCT ', <br>' + cast([testreportingdebug].versions.Name + ': ' + [testreportingdebug].versions.Version AS VARCHAR(max))
        FROM [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].[target]
        FOR XML path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') AS VersionString
        FROM
            [testreportingdebug].[target]
                LEFT JOIN
            [testreportingdebug].[versions] ON [testreportingdebug].[versions].[targetid] = [testreportingdebug].[target].[id]
        WHERE
            [testreportingdebug].[target].[TestJobId] = [testreportingdebug].[testruns].[TestJobId]
                AND [testreportingdebug].[versions].[Name] = 'SW') AS NameVersion
FROM
    [testreportingdebug].[testruns];
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm a bit stuck what/how to rewrite this query. How can I rewrite it to work in SQL Server?

Comment: Post sample data and desired results.  And modern SQL Server has string_agg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Do not rewrite, solve from the same beginning. This will be more simple.

Comment: The error is telling you the issue here, your sub query is returning multiple values, and that isn't allowed. I'm not sure why you are using a subquery inside a subquery; the subquery query should be correlated.

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Same as larnu and I would add that the query makes hardly sense in the actual state. Why would you list all versions in your select clause at all while selecting from another table?? Since you output some <BR> I guess the only goal of this is to display something in an HTML page. Just explain in another question what you need to display and we will help you. You cant rewrite this query in SQL server, if it works in MySQL it is because mysql is more tolerant to non-sense queries like this and do something behind the scene to fix it on its own, and at the end, its a bad move.

Comment: As a side note, if you were using a fully supported version of SQL Server, you would have access to `STRING_AGG`, which is SQL Server's equivalent of `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on? Also if you are trying to create proper XHTML (with opening and closing `br` tags) then there are better methods to use

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server `STRING_AGG()` replaces `GROUP_CONCAT()` and we can specify the seperator as `</br>`.

```sql
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
      versions.Name, 
      ': ', 
      versions.Version,
    '</br') AS VersionString
FROM target
LEFT JOIN versions 
ON versions.targetid = target.id
AND target.TestJobId = testruns.TestJobId
WHERE versions.Name = 'SW';
```